# Octane Blender - beveling edges on a fax/stp mesh

Tags: octane-render-engine

I'm creating a 3D product photography of earbuds. Model is imported .fbx file, converted from .stp file.

Earbuds have sharp edges, in reality they are slightly bevelled.
I've tried all these things, that are usually used for this purpose:

- Round Edges Node in Octane - didn't work
- bevel edge in modelling mode - didn't work
- Weighted Normals - didn't work
- Remesh - its better, but it corrupt other smooth surfaces and smooth modifier didn't help

How would you approach this problem? On which solution should I focus?

[image]

Comment: you say that bevelling the edges in Edit mode doesn't work, but you don't explain why, maybe show the wireframe? or share the file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thank you, please see the file: https://we.tl/t-vgmjh54Ro9

Comment: oh ok yes it's going to be hard to bevel because your topology is rather messy, so I'm ot sure there are any solutions but to either clean the topology or re-do before the bevel